# Installing openJDK along with java oracle

Tags: 14.04, java, jre

I have java oracle 7 installed. To build some library from the source code I do have to install openJDK 7. I don't know why they require but they do require it.

What's the safe way to install openJDK 7 when java oracle 7 is already installed?

Answer (score 1):

openjdk-7-jdk is a installable package. There is no problem with a parallel installation.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

And maybe you should install Oracle Java via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: @jawanam Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: I'll upvote you :) Works perfectly with version 8 as well